# Powershell variable is assigned the result of a function AND the parameter I passed to the function

Tags: function, variables, powershell, pipeline

I'm running into this over and over in my script. I have this line of code:

```
$Errors = Get-DeploymentErrors $uniqueID
```

When this runs, $Errors is assigned the result of Get-DeploymentErrors and the value of $uniqueID. I just want $Errors to be assigned the result of Get-DeploymentErrors.

Here is the Get-DeploymentErrors function:

```
Function Get-DeploymentErrors($uniqueID)
{
$Errors = @()

$conn = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$conn.ConnectionString = 'removed connection string'

$cmd = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$cmd.Connection = $conn
$cmd.CommandText = "removed sql statement"
$cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uniqueID", $uniqueID)

$conn.Open()
$reader = $cmd.ExecuteReader()

if($reader.HasRows)
{
    While ($reader.Read())
    {
        $error = New-Object -TypeName PSObject

        $error | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name StepID -Value $reader["StepID"]
        $error | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DeploymentID -Value $reader["DeploymentID"]
        $error | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name MessageID -Value $reader["MessageID"]
        $error | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Severity -Value $reader["Severity"]
        $error | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Message -Value $reader["Message"]
        $error | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name StepName -Value $reader["StepName"]
        $error | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CurrentStep -Value $reader["CurrentStep"]
        $error | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TotalSteps -Value $reader["TotalSteps"]
        $error | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name CurrentTime -Value $reader["CurrentTime"]

        $Errors += $error
    }
}

return $Errors
}
```

Comment: well i can't run your code, but if i understand you right, you see the $uniqueid result added to the final output? if yes you can add [void] to the start of the line with the $uniqueid, also you can add Write-Output $Errors at the end of your script just above the last parenteses

Comment: @JanChrbolka The function does not appear to be ignoring the argument.

Comment: @Avshalom Yes, that is correct. $Errors is assigned the value of Get-DeploymentErrors and the value of $UniqueID.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks, you learn something every day. Like, don't assume you know the basics :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue()` echoes the added parameter, and PowerShell functions return the entire non-captured output on the [success output stream](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell.aspx), not just the argument of the `return` keyword.

Quoting from [`about_Return`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847760.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> SHORT DESCRIPTION
>   Exits the current scope, which can be a function, script, or script block.
>
> LONG DESCRIPTION
>   The Return keyword exits a function, script, or script block. It can be used to exit a scope at a specific point, to return a value, or to indicate that the end of the scope has been reached.
>
> Users who are familiar with languages like C or C# might want to use the Return keyword to make the logic of leaving a scope explicit.
>
> In Windows PowerShell, **the results of each statement are returned as output, even without a statement that contains the Return keyword.** Languages like C or C# return only the value or values that are specified by the Return keyword.

Use any of the following methods to suppress the undesired output:

- `[void]$cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uniqueID", $uniqueID)`
- `$cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uniqueID", $uniqueID) | Out-Null`
- `$cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uniqueID", $uniqueID) > $null`
- `$param = $cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uniqueID", $uniqueID)`

Comment: Essentially you have to put the output of that command SOMEWHERE or else PowerShell throws it on the pipeline and it gets returned from the function?

Comment: @Dbloom You have to remove it from the [success output stream](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell.aspx). PowerShell functions return all non-captured output on that stream.